# Zoom in interaction on graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code for building X & Y axis:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height*2, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

y.domain([-arr2, arr2]).nice();

var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minD, maxD]).range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
           .scale(x)
           .orient("bottom")
           .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %y'));

xAxis.ticks(d3.time.year, 1)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
      .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", width + 230)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "30px")
    .text("Revision Date");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", 130)
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "30px")
    .text("log(Lev)");
```

Additionally, i have this code creating the circles:

```
var ARdot =  svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(ArticleData)
      .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.Rev_Date)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Log_Lev); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "SteelBlue";});


var TRdot =  svg.selectAll(".dot2")
    .data(TalkpageData)
      .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.Rev_Date)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(-d.Log_Lev); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "LightSeaGreen";});
```

The result (with the code creating the lines of course) is:

[image]

As you can see, blue dots too dense.
I wont to add a zoom in intraction so the user can
zoom in to some part of the graph and the circles and 
the X axis's values and Y axis's values behave according the zoom in.

For example: the closer you get to it, in terms of X axis becomes smaller range for the months of the year and in terms of circles, the distances between them gets bigger.

Comment: Have you had a look at: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior ?

Comment: Thanks to your advice, i learned how to make zoom in and out the axis. 
The problem now is, that the circles aren't affected by the zoom, what can i do to influence the circles also ?

Here is the code that helped make zoom axis only:
[The Code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919)

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)? If you are still blocked, please post a jsFiddle with your code.

Comment: I tried to copy my code to a jsFiddle but i can't upload the two csv files i'm using during running time, so there is no visualizing result in jsFiddle.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle: [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/92QUD/)

Comment: The goal of a stackoverflow question is to show a particular issue and get help on it. In order to do that, you should make your code as concise as possible to show it (half of the times it will also help pin point your problem and you won't have to post a question). So here it means, make your code shorter and simulate the csv load by having a small local dataset.